# Is it better to instantiate a new JdbcTemplate in every query or to inject a single one everywhere?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have a Java library where I access the DB via JDBC using Spring's JDBC support. This library contains approximately a DAO class for each table I need to access, which are over a hundred. Currently I instantiate a new JdbcTemplate, or one of its variants, each time I need to perform a new query. Is this considered good practice or should I reuse a single JdbcTemplate as much as I can? I've actually seen examples of both approaches in either books or online documentation.

The context is a J2EE application, but ideally the code should be usable in different contexts, e.g. in offline tests or command line support tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inject one, why bother instantiating? (It's unclear if you mean "instantiate through the Spring context" or "instantiate using `new`".)

Most samples I've seen do this in the config, I'm not even sure I've seen them instantiated manually outside of demo/test code. I see little benefit to doing it manualy, and zero if done outside of Spring.

Comment: I inherited this library and it was already written in this way.

Comment: as a note it's probably *bad* practice to keep instantiating templates.

Comment: to answer myself, [from the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html): *Instances of the JdbcTemplate class are threadsafe once configured. This is important because it means that you can configure a single instance of a JdbcTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple DAOs (or repositories). The JdbcTemplate is stateful, in that it maintains a reference to a DataSource, but this state is not conversational state.*

Comment: @stivlo I had missed that bit, thank you. I'd say that settles it.

Comment: Yes generally favour injection of JdbcTemplate, it's threadsafe. If you want to fine tune the properties (eg: fetchSize) for a single invocation only, and/or you already have the DataSource for other purposes, you may want to instantiate via new rather than adding an extra JdbcTemplate dependency that requires injection. However, if you are using a JdbcTemplate with the same properties in multiple places and don't need the DataSource, I'd always go with injection. You can have a JdbcTemplate for each specific set of properties you want to set, and inject where needed.

Answer (score 6):

Although there isn't a lot of overhead involved in creating a new JdbcTemplate, there isn't much of a point.  The JdbcDaoSupport class, an abstract class useful for handling JdbcTemplate based DAOs consistently allows each DAO to either inject a DataSource (and undernear the covers instantiates a JdbcTemplate based on that DataSource) or inject a JdbcTemplate.  Since you can do either you would only do the latter if you were looking to customize your JdbcTemplate by setting one or more of the following properties:

- fetchSize
- ignoreWarnings
- maxRows
- nativeJdbcExtractor
- queryTimeout
- skipResultsProcessing
- exceptionTranslator

You would likely have one JdbcTemplate for each combination of these properties. All of these do have defaults, so its only necessary to set them if you are going to override them.  Depending on the diversity of your DAOs, you may have one or many.  Or in the case of extending JdbcDaoSupport, you may have none, having each DAO just wrap the datasource in a default JdbcTemplate undernearth the covers.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of the `JdbcTemplate` class are thread safe once configured, so you can configure a single instance of a `JdbcTemplate` and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple DAOs (or repositories). For more information: [JdbcTemplate-idioms](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms)